# Post-commit-hook in Subversion doesn't work as I want

Tags: batch-file, svn, hook

i came across a problem with subversion at my work. I want to create a post-commit-hook (post-commit.bat file) command that creates information about the last transaction.
The code looks like this:

```
@echo off

set file="D:\mypath\logfile%2.txt"

svn log D:\'my path to repro'\ -r %2 -v > %file%
```

The %2 corresponds to the last revision number. It creates the file with the correct number and tries to write in it. But then the commit hangs and the file remains open. The curious thing is, if I manually trigger the command with a valid revision number, then the whole thing works. Only with the hook it hangs and it also does not commit the files.
Can anyone help me or have any ideas for my problem?

Comment: Only a guess. It could be an authentication issue, perhaps the script, started by the hook asks for credentials

Comment: How can I find out that it asked for credentials?

Comment: Try it with `svn auth > test.txt`, probably you get something like `Credentials cache in '/root/.subversion' is empty`

Comment: I can't access the created logfile, since it is still openend in another process. Maybe that's a hint?

Comment: For those of us who don't use `svn` - what actually happens when you execute that `svn` line from the prompt - step-by-step. Does that command simply return to the prompt, or does something else happen before you get back to the prompt?

Comment: I can easily run the svn command in the prompt. It gives me the exact return that I want. Only when I run it with the hook, it doesn't work...

Comment: That `svn auth` hangs is unexpected, it shouldn't ask you for anything. Did you remove the other lines in your batch? Does `svn --help > test.txt` hangs, too?

Comment: Soory for not answering this long time. I was busy doing other stuff, but now I'm back at this problem. Still unsolved unfortunately :(
@jeb the `svn --help > test.txt` doesn't hang, but also doesn't show any information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, maybe this might be helpful for some person.

I used the wrong command "log". Instead you have to use "svnlook changed..." on the server to get the latest information about the last commit.